# German Grade GPA calculation

Tags: university, germany, gpa, grading

I'm doing MSc in one of the TU9 ([TU9)](https://www.tu9.de/) in Germany where the grading systems work as defined below:

[image]

The grades I have got are as follows:

[image]

I'm wondering how the GPA was calculated as different subjects as different credits and lower the final grade better it is. What mathematical formula is being used to calculate GPA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your GPA has been calculated as the weighted average of your final grades, with the weights being given by the credits for a course divided by the total credits. Numerically this matches the given GPA.

And lower is better here.